# How to make list from datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview

i've downloaded from SQL database items to my datagridview, so i have 8 columns generated automataticaly.

What i'd like to do is to add values from column 5 and 6 to List.

So i'd like to have something like that but make from values from cells.

```
 public List<Item> GetItems()
    {
        return new List<Item>(){
           new Item(){Name = "Usage1", dat=  DateTime.Parse("2012-03-06"},
           new Item(){Name = "Usage2", dat=  DateTime.Parse("2012-03-07"}};

    }
 public class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public datetime dat;

        public Item()
        {
        }
    }
```

How to do it?

Comment: Question is extremely difficult to understand; what SQL and columns are you talking about? You mean `Item` fields? There are only 2; what do "columns 5 and 6" refer to? "something like that but make from values from cells" is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a Linq-Objects query to extract the data from the Rows, then from the Cells in each row.

```
var data = 
    dataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(
        row =>
            new
            {
                 Col5 = row.Cells[Column5.Index].Value,
                 Col6 = row.Cells[Column6.Index].Value,
            })
    .ToList();
```